# NHibernate Session.Flush & Evict vs Clear

Tags: nhibernate, session

In a test where I want to persist an object and then prove it was persisted by fetching it from the db (and not the session), I notice no difference between the following:

```
// save it
session.Clear()
// fetch it
```

or

```
// save it
session.Flush()
session.Evict(_instance)
// fetch it
```

The lazy programmer in me leans towards one line over two. Is there some reason I am missing to favor the two lines more?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

session.Clear actually **cancels** all pending saves/updates/etc.

If it doesn't, it's because you're using identity so the entity is persisted without flushing.

Comment: I *am* using identity - that is a wonderful reason to favor the flush & evict! Cheers

Comment: Btw, wouldn't session.Flush & session.Clear get the same effect as Flush & Evict? I believe it's even better since Evict won't cascade unless defined so.

Comment: @Rita. Yes I think you are right about that. One of the keys to realize about what Diego said is that Clear cancels *pending* saves. What I usually do these days is wrap everything inside of a tranaction; so Save is inside a separate tx and committed via tx.Commit before I call Session.Clear() and therefore not pending. HTH