# Why evicting objects from Session does not commit changes to database?

Tags: nhibernate

I am using NHibernate in my application and have the following situation. (Note that the situation here is much more simplified for the sake of understanding)

An object is queried from the database. It is edited and updated using `Session.Update()`. The object is then Evicted from the Session (using `Session.Evict(obj)`) before the transaction is committed. Expected result is that the changes are persisted to the database.

This used to work fine when I had my `Id` column as a NHibernate `identity` column.
Recently, we changed the Id column to be non-identity. As a result, the above scenario does not persist to the database unless I explicitly call `Session.Flush()` before I Evict.

Can someone point/explain to me the reason for this behavior?

This link, [NHibernate Session.Flush & Evict vs Clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853117/nhibernate-session-flush-evict-vs-clear), mentions something about Evict and the identity column, which to me is not very clear.

Answer (score 9):

Your workflow is not correct.

First, when you retrieve an object from the database, `session.Update(entity)` does not do anything. Changes will happen automatically on `Flush/Commit`

Next, `Evict` removes all knowledge the session has of the object, therefore it will not persist any changes applied to it. You should almost never use this method under normal conditions, which makes me think you are not handling the session correctly.

Third, the fact that using `identity` causes **inserts** to happen immediately on `Save` is a limitation, not a feature.

The correct workflow is:

```
using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var entity = session.Get<EntityType>(id);
    entity.SomeProperty = newValue;
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

The *exact* structure (`using` statements, etc) can change in a desktop application, but the basic idea is the same.

Comment: Diego, you are correct. We had to resort to such 'bad' techniques because a lot of objects were loaded in the session which were readonly. And when the transaction is committed it took some time for the changes to go through. Hence, we thought if we evicted the objects after querying them, we can reduce the objects in the session. The objects that do get updated afterwards are automatically reattached to the session later.
Our first mistake was to use NHibernate for this, but until we can remove it from our system, we are looking for some workarounds to speed things up...

Comment: This particular issue looked strange to me coz, before the changes I made, the Updates somehow got flushed to the database and even after Evicting the objects, I could see the changes. Did NHibernate's AutoFlush did that using some logic that depends on the identity column?
BTW, this is in a web app, so we create a session for every request and commit it at the end. The app is something like a mini-salesforce.com, where users write their own IronPython scripts. That's were they add a lot of readonly objects to the session which we want to Evict. That gave us some performance gain.

Comment: I came over this particular issue by Flushing the session before these Evicts happen. This code is not called extensively, and hence we are okay for now. 
The best recommendation for our project is however, to replace the NHibernate in this layer

Answer (score 2):

Identity forces NHibernate to immediatly save the entity to the database on `session.Save()` non identity allows it to batch the inserts to send them as a whole. Evict will remove all information of the object from the session. So while with identity it forgets about the entity it is already in the database even if the session doesnt know.

to remedy that you can

- set `Flushmode.Auto` (forces immediate flushing)
- call `session.Flush()` before `Evict`
- Evict after the transaction completed

which is the best option depends on the context